# Print array with newlines in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to print an array containing strings representing text lines.

Consider:

```
my $a="1\n2\n3\n";
my @b=split(/^/, $a);
$,="";
print "@b";
```

This gives output:

```
1
 2
 3
```

Notice the space in front of the second and third line. What is the reason for this space, and how to get rid of it?

Comment: Why not `split` on `\n`? I think it's more intuitive if your array elements don't have trailing newlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the space, just use a `for` loop.

```
print for @b
```

or you can edit the `$LIST_SEPARATOR`, `$"` as defined in [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), which by default is a space.

```
local $" = '';
print "@b";
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I confused `$,` with `$"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [join function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html):

```
print join("", @b);
```

That way you don't need to set (and reset maybe) any of the magic vars for different behavious (which can be really confusing, if done too much).